# Sharing ssh keys?

Tags: ssh-keys

I need to access GitHub from multiple cloud VMs. Do I have to create an ssh key on each VM and have a ridiculously long list of keys in my GitHub account, or can I (and even if I can, should I) copy the private ssh key to all the VMs, so that I only need to configure a single public key on GitHub? Is that a) possible and b) stupid?

Comment: You can also try asking this in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Personal Access Token` instead if you don't want to access via ssh. Here is the official [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) about how to do this.